# cocoapods導入済みのプロジェクトをgradleでビルドしようとするとエラー

Tags: ios, xcode, gradle, cocoapods

お世話になります

cocoapodsで、いくつかライブラリを導入したプロジェクトをgradleを使ってビルドしようとしておりますが、なかなかうまくいかず困っております。ググってもそれらしきものが出てこず、当然xcodeではビルドできております

gradleファイルは以下です

```
buildscript {
repositories {
  maven {
    url('http://openbakery.org/repository/')
  }
  mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
  classpath group: 'org.openbakery', name: 'xcodePlugin', version: '0.10.+'
}
```

}

apply plugin: 'xcode'

xcodebuild {
     target = 'NeoCafesagashi'
     workspace = 'NeoCafesagashi.xcworkspace'
   }

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
      gradleVersion = '1.10'
  }

以下のようにエラーが出ます

```
% gradle xcodebuild --stacktrace
:cocoapods
Skipping installing pods, because the Pods directory already exists
:xcodebuildConfig
:infoplistModify
Updating /Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/NeoCafesagashi/NeoCafesagashi-Info.plist
:keychainClean
:keychainCreate SKIPPED
:provisioningClean
:provisioningInstall SKIPPED
:xcodebuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':xcodebuild'.
> Command failed to run (exit code 65): 'xcodebuild -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -target NeoCafesagashi DSTROOT=/Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/dst OBJROOT=/Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/obj SYMROOT=/Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/sym SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/shared'

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':xcodebuild'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.openbakery.CommandRunnerException: Command failed to run (exit code 65): 'xcodebuild -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -target NeoCafesagashi DSTROOT=/Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/dst OBJROOT=/Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/obj SYMROOT=/Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/sym SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/shiratsu/Documents/NeoCafesagashi/build/shared'
    at org.openbakery.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.groovy:88)
    at org.openbakery.XcodeBuildTask.xcodebuild(XcodeBuildTask.groovy:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 44 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.531 secs
```

ググってもいい回答が見つけられず、ちょっとお手上げ気味です
プロジェクトはobjective-cで、xcodeはバージョン6.1です。

どなたかお分かりになる方がいましたら、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

すみません、自己解決しました
まず、stacktraceのログから、xcodebildのコマンドを取り出して、直接実行して確認し、その結果、build.gradleを以下にしました。

```
buildscript {
      repositories {
        maven {
          url('http://openbakery.org/repository/')
        }
        mavenCentral()
      }
      dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.openbakery', name: 'xcodePlugin', version: '0.10.+'
      }
    }

    apply plugin: 'xcode'

    xcodebuild {
      scheme = 'NeoCafesagashi'
      target = 'NeoCafesagashi'
      workspace = 'NeoCafesagashi.xcworkspace'

    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '1.10'
    }
```

結果ビルドが通りました。ひとつ勉強になりました
お騒がせしました